# Android: ScrollView does't clean background when scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, canvas, scrollview

I have very strange problem as you can see pictures below:

[image: Before scrolling]

[image: After scrolling]

Top picture is captured before scrolling and bottom after scrolling. Android doesn't clear the background to erase the starting view. I can fix this if I accept black background (fix can be done by activating the commented code 
android:background="#111100"> in fragment.xml), but I won't do it.

fragment_paavalikko.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/vScroll">
    <!--  android:background="#111100">  -->

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/hScroll">
        <!--  android:background="#111100">  -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/paavalikkoSisalto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="469dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

activity_aktiviteetti1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mannonen.tasavalta.Aktiviteetti1" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/aktiviteetti1Sisalto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity1.java:

```
package com.mannonen.tasavalta;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.*;

public class Aktiviteetti1 extends FragmentActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    PaaValikko fragmentti1;

    //aktiviteetin konstruktori
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aktiviteetti1);

        //päävalikko on fragmentissa, joka pitää lisätä aktiviteettiin heti
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentti1 = new PaaValikko();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.aktiviteetti1Sisalto, fragmentti1);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_aktiviteetti1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

PaaValikko.java

```
package com.mannonen.tasavalta;

import android.support.v4.app.*;

import java.io.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;


public class PaaValikko extends Fragment {

    private ScrollView vScroll;
    private HorizontalScrollView hScroll;
    private Muisti mMuisti;
    private LinearLayout[] mPalstat;
    private LinearLayout mJuuri;
    private TextView mBookmarks;
    private ToggleButton mLanguage;
    private ToggleButton mGraphics;
    private Button mCreateBookmark;
    private Button mHelp;
    private Button mAbout;
    private Button mBookmark1;
    private Button mBookmark2;
    private Button mBookmark3;
    private Button mBookmark4;
    private Button mBookmark5;
    private Button mBookmark6;
    private Button mBookmark7;
    private Button mBookmark8;
    private Button mBookmark9;
    private Button[] mTiedostot;
    private TextView m3D1;
    private TextView m3D2;
    private TextView m3D3;
    private TextView m3D4;
    private TextView m3D5;
    private TextView mStories1;
    private TextView mStories2;
    private TextView mStories3;
    private TextView mStories4;
    private TextView mStories5;
    private String[] mTiedostoNimet;
    private int mNimiLaskuri=0;
    private float mx, my;
    private View mView;

    //Tämä luokka käsittelee päävalikon vakionappien sekä
    //mahdollisten kirjanmerkkien onClick tapahtumat
    class VakioNappi implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int tag=(Integer) v.getTag();
            switch (tag)
            {
                case 2001:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2002:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2003:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2004:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2005:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2006:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2007:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2008:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2009:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2010:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2011:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2012:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2013:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
                case 2014:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    //Tämä luokka käsittelee päävalikon CAD -nappuloiden onClick tapahtumat
    class CADNappi implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int tag=(Integer) v.getTag();
            String tiedostoNimi=mTiedostoNimet[tag];
            v.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000ff);
        }

    }

    //Tämä luokka käsittelee päävalikon teksti -nappuloiden onClick tapahtumat
    class TekstiNappi implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int tag=(Integer) v.getTag();
            String tiedostoNimi=mTiedostoNimet[tag];
            v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff00ff);
        }

    }

    //Tätä metodia kutsutaan, kun fragmentti luodaan, joko dynaamisesti
    //tai xml-tiedostosta
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Aktivoidaan tiedot kovalevyltä, jos jotain on olemassa
        ObjectInputStream sisaan=null;
        try {
            sisaan=new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("Muisti.txt"));
            try {
                mMuisti=(Muisti)sisaan.readObject();
                sisaan.close();
            } catch ( OptionalDataException e) {
                mMuisti=new Muisti();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                mMuisti=new Muisti();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                mMuisti=new Muisti();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            mMuisti=new Muisti();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            mMuisti=new Muisti();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mMuisti=new Muisti();
        }

        // xml tiedostosta luettavat jutut muodostavat View-luokan ilmentymän
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paavalikko, parent, false);
    }

    //Tätä kutsutaan pian onCreateView metodin jälkeen. Kaikkien asetusten
    //määrittäminen laitetaan tänne
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Otetaan käyttöön xml-tiedostossa annettuja juttuja
        mJuuri=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.paavalikkoSisalto);

        //Sitten horisontaaliseen juureen lisätään tarvittavat palstat
        mPalstat=new LinearLayout[mMuisti.annaPalstat()+1];
        for (int i=0; i<mMuisti.annaPalstat()+1; i++) {
            mPalstat[i]=new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
            mPalstat[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            mJuuri.addView(mPalstat[i]);
        }

        //Palstoihin lisätään vakiosisältö, eli otsikot ja painonapit.
        //Aloitetaan vasemmasta palstasta ja vakiosisältö ensin
        mBookmarks=new TextView(view.getContext());
        mBookmarks.setText("Bookmarks");
        mBookmarks.setTextSize(25);
        mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmarks);
        mLanguage=new ToggleButton(view.getContext());
        mLanguage.setTextOff("Finnish");
        mLanguage.setTextOn("English");
        mLanguage.setChecked(true);
        mLanguage.setTag(2001);
        mLanguage.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
        mPalstat[0].addView(mLanguage);
        mGraphics=new ToggleButton(view.getContext());
        mGraphics.setTextOff("Use simple graphics");
        mGraphics.setTextOn("Use elaborate graphics");
        mGraphics.setChecked(true);
        mGraphics.setTag(2002);
        mGraphics.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
        mPalstat[0].addView(mGraphics);
        mCreateBookmark=new Button(view.getContext());
        mCreateBookmark.setText("Create bookmark");
        mCreateBookmark.setTag(2003);
        mCreateBookmark.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
        mPalstat[0].addView(mCreateBookmark);
        mHelp=new Button(view.getContext());
        mHelp.setText("Help");
        mHelp.setTag(2004);
        mHelp.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
        mPalstat[0].addView(mHelp);
        mAbout=new Button(view.getContext());
        mAbout.setText("About");
        mAbout.setTag(2005);
        mAbout.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
        mPalstat[0].addView(mAbout);

        //Sitten lisätään sisältöä muisti-luokan mukaisesti. Kirjanmerkit:
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(0)) {
            mBookmark1=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark1.setText("Bookmark 1");
            mBookmark1.setTag(2006);
            mBookmark1.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark1);
        }
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(1)) {
            mBookmark2=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark2.setText("Bookmark 2");
            mBookmark2.setTag(2007);
            mBookmark2.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark2);
        }
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(2)) {
            mBookmark3=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark3.setText("Bookmark 3");
            mBookmark3.setTag(2008);
            mBookmark3.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark3);
        }
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(3)) {
            mBookmark4=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark4.setText("Bookmark 4");
            mBookmark4.setTag(2009);
            mBookmark4.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark4);
        }
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(4)) {
            mBookmark5=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark5.setText("Bookmark 5");
            mBookmark5.setTag(2010);
            mBookmark5.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark5);
        }
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(5)) {
            mBookmark6=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark6.setText("Bookmark 6");
            mBookmark6.setTag(2011);
            mBookmark6.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark6);
        }
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(6)) {
            mBookmark7=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark7.setText("Bookmark 7");
            mBookmark7.setTag(2012);
            mBookmark7.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark7);
        }
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(7)) {
            mBookmark8=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark8.setText("Bookmark 8");
            mBookmark8.setTag(2013);
            mBookmark8.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark8);
        }
        if (mMuisti.onkoKirjanMerkkia(8)) {
            mBookmark9=new Button(view.getContext());
            mBookmark9.setText("Bookmark 9");
            mBookmark9.setTag(2014);
            mBookmark9.setOnClickListener(new VakioNappi());
            mPalstat[0].addView(mBookmark9);
        }

        //alustetaan mTiedostoNimet, joita voi olla enintään 2000 riippumatta siitä,
        //ovatko teksti- vai CAD-tiedostoja
        mTiedostoNimet=new String[2000];

        //Siirrytään seuraaviin palstoihin vasemmalta oikealle. 3D-palstoja
        //on enintään 5
        boolean luotu=false;
        int index1=0, index2=0;
        mTiedostot=new Button[mMuisti.annaTiedostojenMaara()];
        for (int i=0; i<mMuisti.annaTiedostojenMaara(); i++) {
            if (mMuisti.annaValikkoSijainti(i)==1 && mMuisti.annaOnko3D(i)) {

                //jos palstaan ei ole vielä lisätty, lisätään otsikko
                if (luotu!=true) {
                    index1++;
                    m3D1=new TextView(view.getContext());
                    m3D1.setText("3D 1");
                    m3D1.setTextSize(25);
                    mPalstat[index1].addView(m3D1);
                    luotu=true;
                }

                //luodaan sitten varsinainen valikkokohta
                mTiedostot[index2]=new Button(view.getContext());
                mTiedostot[index2].setText(mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setEnabled(mMuisti.annaOnkoAsetettu(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setTag(mNimiLaskuri);
                mNimiLaskuri++;
                mTiedostot[index2].setOnClickListener(new CADNappi());
                if (mMuisti.annaOnkoNakyva(i)) {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                mPalstat[index1].addView(mTiedostot[index2]);
                index2++;
            }
        }
        luotu=false;
        for (int i=0; i<mMuisti.annaTiedostojenMaara(); i++) {
            if (mMuisti.annaValikkoSijainti(i)==2 && mMuisti.annaOnko3D(i)) {

                 //jos palstaan ei ole vielä lisätty, lisätään otsikko
                if (luotu!=true) {
                    index1++;
                    m3D2=new TextView(view.getContext());
                    m3D2.setText("3D 2");
                    m3D2.setTextSize(25);
                    mPalstat[index1].addView(m3D2);
                    luotu=true;
                }

                //luodaan sitten varsinainen valikkokohta
                mTiedostot[index2]=new Button(view.getContext());
                mTiedostot[index2].setText(mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setEnabled(mMuisti.annaOnkoAsetettu(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setTag(mNimiLaskuri);
                mTiedostoNimet[mNimiLaskuri]=mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i);
                mNimiLaskuri++;
                mTiedostot[index2].setOnClickListener(new CADNappi());
                if (mMuisti.annaOnkoNakyva(i)) {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                mPalstat[index1].addView(mTiedostot[index2]);
                index2++;
            }
        }
        luotu=false;
        for (int i=0; i<mMuisti.annaTiedostojenMaara(); i++) {
            if (mMuisti.annaValikkoSijainti(i)==3 && mMuisti.annaOnko3D(i)) {

                //jos palstaan ei ole vielä lisätty, lisätään otsikko
                if (luotu!=true) {
                    index1++;
                    m3D3=new TextView(view.getContext());
                    m3D3.setText("3D 3");
                    m3D3.setTextSize(25);
                    mPalstat[index1].addView(m3D3);
                    luotu=true;
                }

                //luodaan sitten varsinainen valikkokohta
                mTiedostot[index2]=new Button(view.getContext());
                mTiedostot[index2].setText(mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setEnabled(mMuisti.annaOnkoAsetettu(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setTag(mNimiLaskuri);
                mTiedostoNimet[mNimiLaskuri]=mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i);
                mNimiLaskuri++;
                mTiedostot[index2].setOnClickListener(new CADNappi());
                if (mMuisti.annaOnkoNakyva(i)) {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                mPalstat[index1].addView(mTiedostot[index2]);
                index2++;
            }
        }
        luotu=false;
        for (int i=0; i<mMuisti.annaTiedostojenMaara(); i++) {
            if (mMuisti.annaValikkoSijainti(i)==4 && mMuisti.annaOnko3D(i)) {

                //jos palstaan ei ole vielä lisätty, lisätään otsikko
                if (luotu!=true) {
                    index1++;
                    m3D4=new TextView(view.getContext());
                    m3D4.setText("3D 4");
                    m3D4.setTextSize(25);
                    mPalstat[index1].addView(m3D4);
                    luotu=true;
                }

                //luodaan sitten varsinainen valikkokohta
                mTiedostot[index2]=new Button(view.getContext());
                mTiedostot[index2].setText(mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setEnabled(mMuisti.annaOnkoAsetettu(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setTag(mNimiLaskuri);
                mTiedostoNimet[mNimiLaskuri]=mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i);
                mNimiLaskuri++;
                mTiedostot[index2].setOnClickListener(new CADNappi());
                if (mMuisti.annaOnkoNakyva(i)) {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                mPalstat[index1].addView(mTiedostot[index2]);
                index2++;
            }
        }
        luotu=false;
        for (int i=0; i<mMuisti.annaTiedostojenMaara(); i++) {
            if (mMuisti.annaValikkoSijainti(i)==5 && mMuisti.annaOnko3D(i)) {

                //jos palstaan ei ole vielä lisätty, lisätään otsikko
                if (luotu!=true) {
                    index1++;
                    m3D5=new TextView(view.getContext());
                    m3D5.setText("3D 5");
                    m3D5.setTextSize(25);
                    mPalstat[index1].addView(m3D5);
                    luotu=true;
                }

                //luodaan sitten varsinainen valikkokohta
                mTiedostot[index2]=new Button(view.getContext());
                mTiedostot[index2].setText(mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setEnabled(mMuisti.annaOnkoAsetettu(i));
                mTiedostot[index2].setTag(mNimiLaskuri);
                mTiedostoNimet[mNimiLaskuri]=mMuisti.annaTiedostonNimi(i);
                mNimiLaskuri++;
                mTiedostot[index2].setOnClickListener(new CADNappi());
                if (mMuisti.annaOnkoNakyva(i)) {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mTiedostot[index2].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                mPalstat[index1].addView(mTiedostot[index2]);
                index2++;
            }
        }
        luotu=false;
/*

A part of code removed to save space

                        */
    }
}
```

Muisti.java:

```
package com.mannonen.tasavalta;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Muisti implements Serializable {

    //Alla olevat ovat kirjanmerkkejä varten
    private double[][] kirjanMerkkiOrientaatioD;
    private String[] kirjanMerkkiTiedostoD;
    private double[][] kirjanMerkkiOrientaatioT;
    private String[] kirjanMerkkiTiedostoT;
    private boolean[] kirjanMerkkiOnkoAsetettu= {false, false, false, false,
        false, false, false, false, false};

    //Alla olevat ovat valikkomäärittelyitä varten
    private String[] tiedostoTietoNimi= {"Sampo", "Frame_of_Sampo", "Cell",
        "Liike", "Liike2", "Liike3", "Liikesampo", "Pilvi1", "Pilvi2",
        "Universe", "Logic", "Cosmology", "Mathematics", "Relativity",
        "Reality", "Reality2", "Viides", "Test", "Fft", "FloatTaulukko",
        "Listat"};
    private int[] tiedostoTietoValikkoSijainti= {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};
    private boolean[] tiedostoTietoOnkoNakyva={true, true, true, true, true,
        true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true,
        true, false, true, true, true, true};
    private boolean[] tiedostoTietoOnkoAsetettu= {true, true, true, true,
        true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true,
        true, true, true, true, true, true, true};
    private boolean[] tiedostoTietoOnko3D= {true, true, true, true, true,
        true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false,
        false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    private int tiedostoTietoTiedostoTietoja=21;

    //Alla oleva ilmoittaa palstojen kokonaismäärän ilman Bookmarks-palstaa
    private int palstoja=5;

    public Muisti() {}
    public int annaPalstat() {return palstoja;}
    public boolean onkoKirjanMerkkia(int num) {return kirjanMerkkiOnkoAsetettu[num];}
    public int annaTiedostojenMaara() {return tiedostoTietoTiedostoTietoja;}
    public int annaValikkoSijainti(int num) {return tiedostoTietoValikkoSijainti[num];}
    public boolean annaOnko3D(int num) {return tiedostoTietoOnko3D[num];}
    public String annaTiedostonNimi(int num) {return tiedostoTietoNimi[num];}
    public boolean annaOnkoAsetettu(int num) {return tiedostoTietoOnkoAsetettu[num];}
    public boolean annaOnkoNakyva(int num) {return tiedostoTietoOnkoNakyva[num];}

}
```

I need refreshing white or grey background. I have tested this code by Android Studio with an emulator and Eclipse with a device, and the problem exists on both.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you looking into a fragment behind your scrollview with transparent background, there's too much code to look at, but if you not intended to call fragmentManager.add twice you must search if you are readding the same only one you want.

If you intended to use add (and can't use replace) you must set the background color of the scrollview for something opaque.

On orientation changes the fragments are retained so you need to change your code to `if (savedInstance != null) fragment.add` else it will add another one on top at orientation changes

Comment: Let's continue writing... My code contains only one fragmentTransaction.add but no fragmentManager.add (as far as I can see). Are those fragmentManager.add calls outside the code I have written? And yes, I have to add the buttons dynamically to the view because their number wary. Furthermore, I have found, that my code above works well as far as I don't switch from portrait to landscape or vice versa. Does it give you some symptons about what could be wrong?

Comment: On orientation changes the fragments are retained so you need to change your code to if savedInstance != null fragment.add else it will add another one on top at orientation changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the missing if-clause in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aktiviteetti1);

    //päävalikko on fragmentissa, joka pitää lisätä aktiviteettiin heti,
    //jollei sitä ole jo lisätty
    if (savedInstanceState==null) {     //this was missing original code
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentti1 = new PaaValikko();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.aktiviteetti1Sisalto, fragmentti1);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Thank you Marcos, without your help I couldn't find this bug!

Case closed.